# How to wrap XML in SOAP envelope with Informatica?

Tags: xml, soap, informatica

I have created a Mapping which generates an XML target. Now I need to wrap the XML into a SOAP envelope. What is best way to approach this? I am new to Informatica. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To have SOAP request and response strategy you can use **Web Service Consumer Transformation**
Web Service Consumer Transformation is created to access web service from informatica. It can access either customised web services or external provider services. Transformation cab be created using Web Service Description Language (WSDL) data object. WSDL uses SOAP messages to request and receive requested data. For example in the same data, ID can be passed as a request message and the data of that particular ID is retrieved as a response as SOAP message. Initially WSDL is to be imported and transformation is created. Pass the input ports to SOAP request message and extract output ports from SOAP response message, then provide connection to the web service. Finally pass it to the target.
Verify this site for more information - https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/web_services_consumer